# Control the appearance of itemize items

Tags: itemize

I am trying to order an itemize table. I upload the image and a MWE which produces it:

[image]

And the MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside
%,draft descomentando produce el pdf sin imágenes
]{report}
%document class define parámetros generales para un reporte
%preambulo
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry}
%aca utilizo la geometría de la hoja 
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
%interprete de idioma castellano
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %relacionado al input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0.5cm]
    \item Método de solvatación.\newline\bigskip
    Se analizan dos programas de solvatación.
    \item Cálculo de pKa.\newline\bigskip
    Se analiza un conjunto de reacciones de desprotonación.
    \item Cálculo de la energía libre de un conjunto de reacciones metabólicas.\newline\bigskip
    Se analizan nueve reacciones que forman parte de la glucólisis o del ciclo de Krebs.
    \item Aplicación de la metodología a la bioquímica del Benznidazol.\newline\bigskip
    Estudio de moléculas pertenecientes a la ruta metabólica del Benznidazol.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I want the sentence below the items to be moved down. And I don't know if I am using in the right way \newline\bigskip.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you simply do the following?

1. Put a blank line in place of `\newline\bigskip`. In that way, you are effectively putting a `\par` at the point.
2. Set the option, `parsep=\bigskipamount`. `parsep` sets the rubber space between paragraphs within an item. Now, as you have  implicitly put
   a `\par` in the previous step, this is the rubber length that is effectively introduced here.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %relacionado al input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0.5cm,parsep=\bigskipamount]
    \item Método de solvatación.

      Se analizan dos programas de solvatación.
    \item Cálculo de pKa.

      Se analiza un conjunto de reacciones de desprotonación.
    \item Cálculo de la energía libre de un conjunto de reacciones
      metabólicas.

      Se analizan nueve reacciones que forman parte de la glucólisis o
      del ciclo de Krebs.

    \item Aplicación de la metodología a la bioquímica del
      Benznidazol.

      Estudio de moléculas pertenecientes a la ruta metabólica del
      Benznidazol.
 \end{itemize}
 \end{document}
```

*Please don't worry about `babel`, that language is not available in my machine.*

---

[image]

Comment: great. It wasn't that working yesterday. I will try and accept if it works. Thanks!

Comment: @HernanMiraola Please let me know if you face any specific problem. In my computer it worked without the slightest problem.